# Data hiding in Image

Tags: ios, steganography

I am hiding a text file in an image using http://github.com/anirudhsama it works fine and I could able to extract the text file again back with my program.

But when I programmatically share the image in facebook, twitter and email, that shared image is not decode properly so I'm not getting the file back.

I retrive the image as follows:

```
UIImage *finalImageWithStegno = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without any sort of explanation as to how you're hiding the text.

Comment: I am using this to hide the file in a image https://github.com/anirudhsama/. When im sharing that image in social media by retriving with   UIImage *finalImageWithStegno = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName]; and im sharing the finalImageWithStegno.

Comment: Can you post example pictures that show your problem?

Comment: Perhaps Facebook doesn't want images with hidden information in them?  Maybe they're stripping it out?

Answer (score 5):

What I suspect is image compression when it is uploaded to the site. A simple way to check this is to hide a message in a cover image (obtain stego image). Upload the image on a website and download it. Compare the original stego image to the downloaded image. If they differ (byte by byte), there's your problem.

From a quick look at the code, it seems the app hides the data in the spatial domain, which is not robust. Your message is directly hidden in the image pixels and if they change (due to lossy compression, blurring, etc), your message will be lost. A solution to this would be to hide the data in the frequency domain. Another solution could be uploading the images with a filetype which doesn't get compressed? I don't know much how sites deal with images so the second suggestion may be impossible.

In any case, if uploading to a site distorts the image, look around for another app which may serve you unless you can code yourself. Then we can get into the specifics. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is not robust. Use Transform domain Stegnography to retain the information when its is re encoded. You may choose to embed in DCT coefficients or DWT Coefficients for better robustness.